# Blinking effect on UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I have a UILabel with background color as grey.

I want a blinking effect on this label like it should become a little white & then become gray and it should keep happen till I turn it off programatically.

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: extension UIView{
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                                   delay: 0.0,
                                   options: [.curveLinear,
                                             .repeat,
                                             .autoreverse],
                                   animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 },
                                   completion: nil)   
    }
}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer 
                      scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(1.0)
                            target:self 
                             selector:@selector(blink) 
                             userInfo:nil 
                             repeats:TRUE];
BOOL blinkStatus = NO;
```

in your blink function

```
-(void)blink{
   if(blinkStatus == NO){
      yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     blinkStatus = YES;
   }else {
      yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
      blinkStatus = NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use BOOL, YES and NO rather than bool, TRUE and FALSE ? Thx.

Comment: @DCMaxxx Yes. One of my early(nostalgic) iOS programming bad practices. Corrected now. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Speaking of bad practices. Repeating timers at 60fps... this should be an animation (there is discrete animations for when you don't want any interpolation between the values)

Comment: Nice. The UIView animation example work on fading the alpha. OP wanted a BLINK effect. This does it.

Answer (score 57):

You can do this within a block:

```
self.yourLabel.alpha = 1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 0;
} completion:nil];
```

So you dont need a second method.

Comment: This is a nice alternative, although it's more of a slow fade in/out than a blink. Note you can stop the animation by using `[self.yourLabel.layer removeAllAnimations]`.

Comment: you could `.alpha = 1;` the first time and in the animation block `.alpha = 0;` this will avoid a weird blinking at the start of the animation.

Answer (score 34):

**Swift 3**

```
extension UILabel {

    func startBlink() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8,
              delay:0.0,
              options:[.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
              animations: { self.alpha = 0 }, 
              completion: nil)
    }

    func stopBlink() {
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
        alpha = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have a button named "btn" how would i call the function to start?

Comment: Within the button's action, you have to call yourLabelName.startBlink()

Comment: Nice solution. Works as a charm

Answer (score 23):

You can simply make an extension to the **UILabel** class that will support the *blinking* effect. I don't think using a timer is a right approach since you won't have any fade effect.

Here is the **Swift** way to do this:

```
extension UILabel {
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, //Time duration you want,
                            delay: 0.0,
                          options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .Autoreverse, .Repeat],
                       animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 },
                       completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 0.0 })
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
extension UILabel {
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 0.0 })
    }
}
```

**EDIT Swift 3: Works for almost any view**

```
extension UIView {
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 0.0 })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this, somehow it's not working. No error message. Just doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

A different approach but works. Blinking only for 3 seconds

```
extension UIView {
  func blink() {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fromValue           = 1
    animation.toValue             = 0
    animation.duration            = 0.8
    animation.autoreverses        = true
    animation.repeatCount         = 3
    animation.beginTime           = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather use the view animations. It makes it very simple and is easy to control. Try this:

```
self.yourLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.12
  delay:0.0
  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | 
          UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | 
          UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | 
          UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
  animations:^{
   self.yourLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
// Do nothing
}];
```

You can tweak the values to get different effects for example, changing animateWithDuration wil set the blinking speed. Further you can use it on anything that inherits from UIView example a button, label, custom view etc.

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking Krishnabhadra Answer to give a better blink effect

Declare a Class variable `bool blinkStatus;`

And paste code given below

```
NSTimer *yourtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(10.0 / 60.0)  target:self selector:@selector(blink) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
    blinkStatus = FALSE;

-(void)blink{
    if(blinkStatus == FALSE){
        yourLabel.hidden=NO;
        blinkStatus = TRUE;
    }else {
        yourLabel.hidden=YES;
        blinkStatus = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should u use timer?

Comment: hi vishnu when ever you want the label to start blinking

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) startBlinkingLabel:(UILabel *)label 
{
    label.alpha =1.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.32
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         label.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {

                         }
                     }];
}

-(void) stopBlinkingLabel:(UILabel *)label 
{
    // REMOVE ANIMATION
    [label.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity"];
    label.alpha = 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My swift version based on [`Flex Elektro Deimling's` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21558744/649379):

```
private func startTimeBlinkAnimation(start: Bool) {
    if start {
        timeContainerView.alpha = 1
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.3, options:[.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { _ in
            self.timeContainerView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        timeContainerView.alpha = 1
        timeContainerView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got stuck when trying with swift and using multiple options but this seems to work nicely:

```
self.cursorLabel.alpha = 1
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
    self.cursorLabel.alpha = 0
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me. I adapted the answer of @flex_elektro_deimling

First parameter UIView.animateWithDuration is the total time of the animation (In my case I've set it to 0.5), you may set different values on the first and second (delay) to change the blinking speed.

```
    self.YOURLABEL.alpha = 0;
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.5, 
        delay: 0.2, 
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.YOURLABEL.alpha = 1
        },
        completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count;
    NSTimer *timer;

      timer= [NSTimer
                  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(0.5)
                  target:self
                  selector:@selector(animationStart)
                  userInfo:nil
                  repeats:TRUE];

-(void)animationStart{
switch (count) {
    case 0:
        //205   198 115
        count++;
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/255.0f green:198.0f/255.0f blue:115.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 1:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 56  142 142
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255.0f green:142.0f/255.0f blue:142.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 2:
         count++;
        //205   198 115
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/255.0f green:205.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 3:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 84  255 159
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:84.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:159.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 4:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 255 193 37
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:193.0f/255.0f blue:37.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 5:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 205 200 177
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:117.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 6:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 255 228 181
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:228.0f/255.0f blue:181.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 7:
         count++;
        //205   198 115 233 150 122
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:233.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:122.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 8:
        count++;
        //205   198 115 233 150 122
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;
    case 9:
         count=0;
        //205   198 115 255 99  71 255  48  48
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Swift 4.0 with extension for any UIVIew

```
extension UIView{
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                                   delay: 0.0,
                                   options: [.curveLinear,
                                             .repeat,
                                             .autoreverse],
                                   animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 },
                                   completion: nil)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3+**, building on all the great answers here, I ended up with a few tweaks that gave me smooth blinking effect that automatically stops after a given number of cycles.

```
extension UIView {
    func blink(duration: Double=0.5, repeatCount: Int=2) {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in
                UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float(repeatCount) + 0.5)
                self?.alpha = 1.0
            }
        )
    }
}
```