# How to make a Uilabel blink in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blinking effect on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224468/blinking-effect-on-uilabel)

How to make a `UILabel` blink in iPhone. I have tried googling and in SO also. But those questions are animating the label to change the colour. But I dont need to change the colour. I jus need the UILabel to blink. Is it possible?

Comment: You could animate its alpha instead of its color.

Comment: Add a NSTimer Object that toggles the Hidden property.

Comment: @OneGuyInDc Code snippet would be helpful... Am a beginner.

Comment: Ability to use Google would be helpful. http://is.gd/tCqPWD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code snippet :

In your controller create a NSTimer property :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

In your **viewDidLoad** method, start the timer :

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(toggleLabelAlpha) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Finally write the function to toggle the label

```
- (void)toggleLabelAlpha {

    [self.label setHidden:(!self.label.hidden)];
}
```

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

1:  Create a NSTimer Object in your Class

```
NSTimer *updateTimer
```

2:  Instantiate the Timer -

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1000 
                                               target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(appUpdate:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
```

3:    Write a Selector (method) that the timer uses -

```
- (void)appUpdate:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    //Toggle the Text between a empty string and the text you want to display here
}
```

Comment: Looks like the previous post beat me to it