# How to make UIImageView blink/flash animation infinite?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, blink

I'm trying to achieve a blinking/flashing effect with some duration for a UIImageView in my iOS app. I want the UIImageView to blink/flash with alpha, not with different images.

I have another code-snippet from an android app which sort of describe what I'm trying to achieve in XCode Swift. I post it here below:

**This is what I have achieved so far, in XCode Swift:**

```
        ellipses.alpha=0.8
        ellipses.animationDuration=1
        ellipses.animationRepeatCount=0
        ellipses.startAnimating()
```

And of course, it's not working! I'm not really sure on how to achieve this, and would be very happy to get some guidance.

**This code below is for android, not for Swift/Xcode** (But it describes what my goal is pretty clear)

```
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); //to change visibility from visible to invisible
        animation.setDuration(1000); //1 second duration for each animation cycle
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); //repeating indefinitely
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); //animation will start from end point once ended.
        imageButton.startAnimation(animation); //to start animation
```

Comment: Use `UIView` animations

Comment: Can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224468/blinking-effect-on-uilabel/39936878

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following code to get image animation like a blink.

**Image Blink (Using image view hide/show):-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.alarmAlertActivate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func alarmAlertActivate(){
        myImage.isHidden = !myImage.isHidden
    }
```

[image]

**Image Blink (Using image view alpha):-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(self.alarmAlertActivate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

@objc func alarmAlertActivate(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7) {
            self.alarmImage.alpha = self.alarmImage.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I would like to have some opacity/alpha on it, do you have any suggestions on how to implement that as well?

Comment: Yes, you can change the alpha of UIImageView, Just min i will update my code.

Answer (score 11):

You could animate the opacity of the image view repeatedly. Something like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                      delay: 0,
                    options: [.repeat, .autoreverse],
                 animations: { imageView.alpha = 0 }
              )
```

Comment: "Value of type 'UIImageView?' has no member 'opacity'"

Comment: @Logi95 use "alpha"

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make my button blink/flash abruptly, not smoothly fade in and out as most IOS animation do by default. The accepted answer above does this with a timer, but you can set up the regular animator class to do this as well -- without smoothing. Below is an example that blinks the border color of a button, but this can be used on anything that requires the same effect.

The trick here is to use "keyframe" animation, and set calculationMode to "discrete":

```
    let color = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    color.values = [CGColor.white, CGColor.black, CGColor.white]
    color.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
    color.duration = 1
    color.repeatCount = .infinity
    color.calculationMode = .discrete
    gotItButton.layer.borderWidth = 3
    gotItButton.layer.add(color, forKey: "")
```